# Google sheets query on unique range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have two columns Y and Z of some data:

```
Y   Z
G   U
P   U
G   U
G   U
G   P
G   P
P   U
R   U
R   P
C   P
C   U
```

I have got the unique values based on both columns like below:

```
 =UNIQUE(Y1:Z10)
```

I got of course:

```
A B <- columns
G U
P U
G P
U U
U P
C P
C U
```

Then I can get the second column like below:

```
 =QUERY(A1:B10;"select B")
```

So I got:

```
U
U
P
U
P
P
U
```

Great, I thought I have everything ready, just mix formulas:

`=QUERY(UNIQUE(Y1:Z10);"select *")` - > this is working - getting two columns, as expected.
but when I try to select specific column - it's value error - no column "X".

The problem is with column name of course, but yeah, how to get it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only use column letters (e.g., `Z`) if the `QUERY` is acting directly on the actual range. Since you've introduced `UNIQUE`, you've create a virtual array instead of a direct reference; and you must reference columns of virtual arrays within `QUERY` in "Col`x`" format, e.g.:

`=QUERY(UNIQUE(Y1:Z10),"select Col2 WHERE Col2 Is Not Null")`

BTW, you'll want the `WHERE Col2 Is Not Null` in there, since `UNIQUE` counts null as a unique value (i.e., every blank row processed by `UNIQUE` has a null value, which is returned with the results unless you further process it).

Comment: Lol I was testing the formula:
=QUERY(UNIQUE(Y1:Z10),"select col2 WHERE col2 Is Not Null") (c instead of C)...
Thank you for the answer!

Comment: Happy to have helped.